# Highcharts - Gray out only title in legend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Is it possible to gray out only title of hidden serie in highcharts legend (not the color marker)? Picture worth 1000 words.

[image: Default behavior]
[image: What I want]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, a wrapping of `Legend.colorizeItem` which post-processes the legend items `legendLine` and `legendSymbol` to "undo" the setting of the hidden color:

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'colorizeItem', function (proceed, item, visible) {
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        if(item.legendLine) {
            item.legendLine.attr({ stroke: item.color });
        }
        if(item.legendSymbol) {
            if ((item.options && item.options.marker) && item.legendSymbol.isMarker)
                item.legendSymbol.attr(item.pointAttribs());
            else
                item.legendSymbol.attr({ fill: item.color });
        }
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

The elaborate code for `item.LegendSymbol` is to preserve any marker options that may be set. It mimics the default behavior of `colorizeItem` without considering `visible`s truthness.

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/kcnyupo8/18/) of it in use.

Comment: Thank you. Works as I expected.

Answer (score 3):

You could apply CSS to style the legend to achieve your desired effect.

Specifically, take advantage of the `highcharts-legend-item-hidden` class that gets added on each legend item (i.e. after it gets clicked on to hide the series) to force the colour of the marker to stay the same colour.

For example, to ensure the legend marker of the first data series always stays as `#ff6600`:

```
.highcharts-series-0.highcharts-legend-item-hidden .highcharts-graph {
    stroke: #ff6600;
}
.highcharts-series-0.highcharts-legend-item-hidden .highcharts-point {
    fill: #ff6600;
}
```

[Here's a demonstration.](http://plnkr.co/edit/EkXvrS?p=preview)